# FOP min-height not working?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to force a block have a minimum height. But nothing continues to happen. If I use height instead of min-height, then the height works, but is fixed.

```
<fo:block-container min-height="4cm">
    <fo:block background-color="blue">Foobar</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

The FOP compliance page claims support is complete, so I guess I'm doing it wrong. https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

Comment: It does not work for Apache FOP. It does with other formatters. One note for you ... you would never see the blue background around the whole area unless you put that color on the block-container and not the included block.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So the compliance page is wrong. Great.

And thanks for the clarification on the background. This was just a modified example of what I have. My case has borders on the block-container.

Comment: I will check which version of FOP I tested, which version are you using?

Comment: I was using FOP version 2.1, tested both min-height as well as block-progression-dimension.minimum and neither worked, Both min-height and block-progression-dimension give the expected result using RenderX XEP. I would submit bug report to Apache FOP.

Answer (score 0):

min-height is not supported in FOP 2.0 according to Kevin Browns comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try `block-progression-dimension.minimum="4cm"`, since `min-height` maps to `block-progression-dimension` (or to `inline-progression-dimension`, depending on the writing mode and reference orientation).  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#min-height and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e4413

Comment: I tried that, I just forgot to mention it. I think min-height is just a css-shorthand for the same. Neither works.